# PayPal IPN for recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

With regular PayPal IPN we receive a payment notification immediately after someone pays.

But how does it work with monthly recurring payments? When we receive an IPN for a recurring payment? every month? only when subscribed/unsubscribed/failed?

Please give me the details and refer to a help page at the PayPal's site.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is Googling `paypal ipn recurring payments`, have you tried that?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I get a page with *broken* link to https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20161016-1/en_US/pdf/subscriptions.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an IPN any time a new profile is created, suspended, canceled, reactivated, and you will also get IPNs for every payment associated with a profile.

Comment: I know this is four years old but as of Dec 2020, there is no IPN sent on reactivation of a subscription/recurring payment. There is for created, suspended and cancelled though.